# module 'jwt' has no attribute 'ExpiredSignature'

Tags: django, jwt, graphene-django, pyjwt, django-graphql-jwt

I have been developing a Django application using graphene/graphql running over AWS using Docker alpine image. I have been using django-grapql-jwt-0.3.1 module for calling jwt-2.0.0 authentication in my application. Where it is calling ExpiredSignature from PyJWT instead of ExpiredSignatureError. And graphQL is returning "module 'jwt' has no attribute 'ExpiredSignature'" error. How to resolve the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

it's a compatibility issue,

downgrade `PyJWT` to `1.7.1`

source: https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/issues/242